# use container name for commands in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I run

> docker-compose ps

in my project I get a list of containers with Name, Command, State and Ports specified. Name looks like this:

> prefix_real_container_name_1

If I use the full name to execute commands like:

> docker-compose stop prefix_real_container_name_1

then I get an error:

> No such service: prefix_real_container_name_1

But the following works:

> docker-compose stop real_container_name

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Using `docker-compose` to access your containers will always require to pass a service name as a parameter, currently no way to change that.

But you can use `container_name` keyword in your compose file like this:

```
services:
   random_service:
      container_name: random_service
      # other definitions
```

explicitly naming the container the same as your service name (like `random_service`) so that it'll appear the same in `docker ps` and `docker-compose ps` and you'll be able to address it the same from:

```
$ docker stop random_service
```

and

```
docker-compose stop random_service
```

Comment: Thats what i do too .

Answer (score 0):

Docker compose is adding some text pre- and postfixes to avoid collision with other containers name, like if you run two containers with node then without unique name them you and docker would have problems recognizing them

Comment: Can I make it work with whatever is displayed in terminal? It's getting annoying to always remove prefix and postfix after copying the container name.